# update 2 record in different date?

Tags: php, mysql

I got a question regarding if I want update 2 record by only one command, isn't possible do like this ?

```
mysql_query("UPDATE damacaicheck SET trimresult = '$trim' where date = '$Current' and date = '$yesterdaydate'");
```

or

`mysql_query("UPDATE damacaicheck SET trimresult = '$trim' where date in ('$Current','$yesterdaydate')");`

Comment: You can do that. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: And how about accepting some answers :). It's the reason people answer to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `date = '$Current' AND date = '$yesterdaydate'"` use `date = '$Current' OR date = '$yesterdaydate'"`

Answer (score 0):

Your first example needs to use OR rather than AND.

Answer (score 0):

There was a no issue on your query problem is its may not return any value use `OR` instead of `AND` as previous posters said